# SQL check if value exists in group

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table of channel members

```
channelID  | accountID  | role
------------------------  
1          | Bob   | 100
2          | Bob   | 100
1          | Dave  | 101
```

and another table of channels

```
channelID  | channelName     | type 
---------------------------------------  
1          | Public Channel  | public
2          | Private Channel | private
```

How would I go about getting channels that a user is not in that are public?

I attempted doing this but cannot figure out how to group channel members table since there are two items with channelID 1 so when I do my query if I search with user Dave I get channel 1 as a result when it should return nothing. My query that I'm using:

```
Select ChatChannels.channelID, channelName, type
From ChatChannels
INNER JOIN ChatChannelMembers
On ChatChannels.channelID = ChatChannelMembers.channelID
Where AccountID = 'Dave'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT (stuff)
FROM ChatChannels CC
WHERE CC.type = 'Public'
  AND CC.channelID NOT IN (SELECT channelID FROM ChatChannelMembers WHERE AccountID = 'Dave')
```

Comment: No your query provides the same result as my query. What I want the query to provide is a list of channels that are public and that the user is not listed for in the channelMembers table. Don't know if it's something you can do with sql? May have to process on client side?